# Add or modify JSON string

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm curious as to whether or not you can add or modify an incoming JSON string in a console application. For example, I have a JSON string with firstname, lastname, and street with values in those fields. Is it possible to add to or modify those values assosciated to those fields from user input?

EDIT: First, sorry, I should have been a lot more clear. So far I have converted the dataset/datatable from SQL database into a JSON string and can display the JSON string to the console. I have then converted the JSON string back to a dataset with a custom function "ConvertJSONToDataTable". In my SQL Database there is a table Applicant, with these fields: LastName, FirstName, Street, Title, State, ZIP, PhoneNumber. I'm really confused as to how to start this. Maybe I'm just overthinking it. I need to write out to the console "Enter First Name: " and then "Enter Last Name: ", etc, etc, and the value entered should change with the existing value in the datatable. This is what my teacher wants: *Try writing some code that implements adding and modifying based on an incoming JSON string*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are plenty of .NET resources for working with JSON. You can probably even find some VB examples on the Google.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything helpful. Also, I cannot use third party helpers.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your need for no 3rd party helpers. Make sure to include details like that in your question.

Comment: Hi Nate, thank you so much for your help. I updated my question as I'm just realizing I wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` Then add this import statement:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

You will need a class which matches the JSON structure:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property FirstName() As String
    Public Property LastName() As String
    Public Property Street() As String
End Class
```

You can figure out how to get the user input and the starting JSON string, but using the built in .net deserialization, you can map your JSON to an object like so:

```
Dim json = "{ FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe', Street: '1234 Dale Street' }"

Dim javaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim person = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(Of Person)(json)

person.FirstName = "Joe"
person.LastName = "Dirt"
```